# I received offer proposal but not offer letter yet due to winter holidays. Should I resign now?

Tags: job-offer, resignation, job-change, india

I am from India.

I recently got a call from recruiter that I have been finalized for a job after successful interview rounds and he told me that he would be marking DOJ(Date of Joining) as 1 month after this call. Then next day I got an email that includes compensation details and asked me if I agree upon numbers. It also states that final offer letter will be released after my acceptance and successive approvals. I replied that I accept the proposal. I also got mail where I had to fill some forms and upload some documents for BG verification and COI(Conflict Of Interest) form where I had to fill my new manager's and recruiter's name. But due to winter holidays, my final offer letter would be delayed for some days.

My query is should I resign now or after receiving final offer letter keeping in mind that recruiter is marking my DOJ as 1 month after the call?

Comment: "You've given notice? Great. Unfortunately those details were printed in error and from a different role. Besides, we can't offer that this year due to policy out of my control. Here's your actual offer now that it's that or unemployment."

Comment: What are the advantages or benefits of resigning before getting the final offer from the other company ?  Everyone agrees that you should only turn in the resignation letter after you get the final offer from the other company.

Comment: You said the amount of time you needed to wait was a number of days.  Then wait those days.  The hiring date they want is the 1st?  Tell them they have to alter it to later so you can properly leave your employer.  If they seem surprised, tell them it's a proper courtesy, you wouldn't harm your employer by doing otherwise, and if you ever leave them, they'll get the same courtesy because it's the right thing to do.  Most people will let employees follow the rules in leaving, especially when it means they will follow the rules for their company too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, *never* resign until you have a formal, signed offer from your new employer. See many, many questions on this site for times it's gone wrong.

> he told me that he would be marking DOJ(Date of Joining) as 1 month after this call

Get back in contact with the recruiter. Tell them you won't be joining until one month after you receive the offer letter.

Comment: I don't know how many times we need to repeat this suggestion - "Don't let the rope go until you have secured another one to hang on".

Comment: "Tell them you won't be joining until one month after you receive the offer letter."  This is unnecessary unless the applicant desires to start work later.

Comment: @Tiger Guy: It could be necessary if querent's current contract requires a one-month notice of termination.

Comment: @TigerGuy One month (or even three month) notice periods are common in India, so that seems likely.

Comment: Yeah, I have learned on this board about India and releasing letter, etc. So OP needs to line up the dates from the new joining letter with enough time to get the old job sorted.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Never resign until you have a formal offer and you have accepted the offer and have set a start date. If the recruiter sets a start date that you don't like, tell them it doesn't work. Then once you have everything set for the new job, you can resign and tell the currently employer when your last day will be.